Issue with Adding Comments to Excel Cells using ClosedXML 0.102.2
I'm trying to add comments to specific cells in an Excel file using the ClosedXML library (version 0.102.2) in my C# project. However, when I open the generated Excel file, I encounter the following error:
Entfernte Datensätze: Kommentare von /xl/comments1.xml-Part (Kommentare)
It seems like there's a problem with the comments part of the XML structure in the Excel file. Here's the code I'm using:

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create a new workbook
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            // Add a worksheet
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

            // Access a specific cell
            var cell = worksheet.Cell("A1");

            // Set a value in the cell (optional)
            cell.Value = "Hello, World!";

            // Create a comment and add text
            var comment = cell.CreateComment();
            comment.AddText("This is a comment.");

            // Optionally, set properties for the comment
            comment.SetVisible(); // Make the comment visible
            comment.Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLDrawingHorizontalAlignment.Left);
            comment.Style.Alignment.SetVertical(XLDrawingVerticalAlignment.Top);
            comment.Style.Font.SetFontSize(10); // Set font size

            // Save the workbook
            workbook.SaveAs("SampleWorkbook.xlsx");
        }
    }
}

Questions:
1- What might be causing this issue with the comments in the Excel file?
2. Is there a different approach or method to add comments to cells that might avoid this error?
3. Are there known issues with the ClosedXML version 0.102.2 related to comments?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have the same issue. Im doing this, and no comment is visible in the resultant excel file:
comment.SetVisible();
comment.AddText("My Comment");```
